# Choosing Filter Options in a Telerik MVC3 Grid using Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, filtering, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am playing about with the Telerik MVC3 extensions and in particular the Grid, which can be seen [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid)

I am using custom paging and interested in the options around filtering.

It is easy enough to allow filtering per column with the following:

```
.Columns(x =>
{
    x.Bound(col => col.Id).Filterable(false);
```

However it seems as though I have no choice over which options are presented to the user when I do enable it. No matter the field, I get the following in the filter dropdown:

[image: Filter Options]

Ideally I'd only want 'Contains' - is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution is like this:

**Telerik GRID** code:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.MRUCode).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "FilterOnlyOn_Contains" });
```

**JavaScript** code:

```
$(".FilterOnlyOn_Contains .t-filter").click(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        // Remove all existing options and add 'Contains'
        var filterOptions1 = $(".t-filter-operator").first();
        filterOptions1.empty();
        filterOptions1.append($("<option />").val("substringof").text("Contains"));

        // Remove second part (options + text + input)
        var filterOptions2 = $(".t-filter-operator").last();
        filterOptions2.hide();
        $(".t-filter-help-text").text("");
        $("input[type=text]").last().hide();
    });
});
```

**Result** looks like:
[image]

Comment: I only wish I could upvote this more than once. Absolutely spot on solution to the problem I posted, thank you.

Comment: This solution works for me only for the first column filtered. Looks like telerik filter html is added to the dom on every click, so First and Last stops targeting the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by Stef is the one that was implemented in our application, but I noticed it didn't work for cases where multiple columns were filterable. I have made a small change to the JS to allow multiple column filtering with Stef's solution. Essentially, its the same code (so all upvotes to Stef). It simply takes a further step in grouping by "t-animation-container"s (as that is the element the filters are rendered to), and acting on each individually as Stef's code did to the page.

```
$(".FilterOnlyOn_Contains .t-filter").click(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {

        var $animationContainers = $(".t-animation-container");
        $animationContainers.each(function () {
            // Remove all existing options and add 'Contains'
            var filterOptions1 = $(this).find(".t-filter-operator").first();
            filterOptions1.empty();
            filterOptions1.append($("<option />").val("substringof").text("Contains"));

            // Remove second part (options + text + input)
            var filterOptions2 = $(this).find(".t-filter-operator").last();
            filterOptions2.hide();
            $(".t-filter-help-text").text("");
            $("input[type=text]").last().hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Just after coming up with this solution, I found another issue with it. It no longer targets "t-animation-container"s which are joined to the "FilterOnlyOn_Contains" filter. It affects all filters and hence edits elements we don't want it to. I don't know how this relationship is made, I guess there are js dom references that the telerik js file makes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you can remove other options but you can set the "contains" option as a default item by putting the following code in your grid_load client-side event :

```
  $("#gridId").find(".t-filter").click(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".t-filter-operator").each(function () {
                $(this).val("substringof");
            });
        });
```

I think you can remove other items easily by tracing the above code in FireBug or Chrome Developer Tools.

Answer (score 0):

if it is possible I suspect you need to take a look in the telerik.grid.filtering.js javascript file and edit it to your wishes.